# How to verify DBCC CHECKDB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, jobs, dbcc-checkdb

I am logging the `DBCC CHECKDB` job output to a table.

When I look at the job log using the below command, I want to verify that all is well.

```
use msdb
EXEC dbo.sp_help_jobsteplog
@job_name = N'DatabaseIntegrityCheck - USER_DATABASES' ;
```

Would you say that we are good if we see "Outcome: Succeeded" in the log for the job or is there something else we should also review?

We are using Ola's job output but I am also logging it to a table and am just wondering about the output. If we see "outcome succeeded' in the job, is this enough to know the `CHECKDB` found nothing wrong?